# class not work after use in media screen CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have below style in my style.css:

```
.adbox {
    background: #304254;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 468px;
    height: 66px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Now I used it in media screen code for responsive, like below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    /* -=>Meta */
    .meta {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    /* -=>Blog Block */
    .blog-block h2 {
        margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
    }
    .blog-block .summary {
        height: auto;
    }

    .adbox {
      background: #304254;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 458px;
      height: 66px;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 231px;
      margin-top: -111px;
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="adbox">
  <a href="google.com">
   <img class="img-responsive tablighatextra" src="0098.in/uyedfuygwecgeifg/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/…; alt="تبلیغات" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Now it not work and in inspect element all code is not usable:

[image]

and HTML code is below:

```
<div class="adbox"><a href="http://google.com"><img class="img-responsive tablighatextra" src="http://0098.in/uyedfuygwecgeifg/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/814d302fbaf4ba308e6eba7a7e7b6f28.gif" alt="تبلیغات" /></a></div>
```

Comment: can we see the html code?

Comment: Place your media query atmost bottom it will work.

Comment: May be your css will conflict with other css..

Comment: @spoloso, pls include the html code in the post

Comment: Media query should be placed at the last line of your css.

Comment: @spoloso i noticed you have scrolled down alittle on that screenshot to find the class, the top most element is what is overriding it, click on the actual element and upload a screenshot, the element AT THE TOP IS WHAT WOULD BE OVER-RIDING IT

Comment: i add html code in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `!important` at the end of each style for example `padding: 5px !important;`

Comment: Thanks, it works, what mean when we add "!important" at the end of each line?

Comment: Avoid using !important. It's a worst part of css

Comment: no its not i use it allot and i do lots of coding for plenty of customers and the site come out okay

Comment: i mean comes out great

Comment: i have taken my code back.. i didn't know when i was writing my code your answer was already posted. do apologize..

Comment: well delete it if you are truely sorry

Answer (score 2):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3cuxje6w/)

it seems to be working fine. Check your CSS, media queries should be at the bottom of your CSS.

```
.adbox {
    background: #304254;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 468px;
    height: 66px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    /* -=>Meta */
    .meta {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    /* -=>Blog Block */
    .blog-block h2 {
        margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
    }
    .blog-block .summary {
        height: auto;
    }

    .adbox {
      background: #304254;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 458px;
      height: 66px;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 231px;
      margin-top: -111px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you try removing the 'screen' or 'only' and using only the media?

If it work, you are an step closer to the solution. It worked for me many times.

Answer (score 1):

As I found both the rules have common properties.
So if two rules have exactly the same selector and both have common properties then the values of lastly declared rules will be applicable (if none of them have !important).
So I assume that your media query is declared before the rule that have the same properties.

Solution :

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
/* your other rules */

    .adbox {
    margin-left: 231px !important;
    margin-top: -111px !important;
    }
}
```

I removed other values as they have not changed inside media query.

other solution is that you declare media query section after your rule that appears in media query (.adbox).